# How to get the relative URL for the rendered document?

Tags: docpad

Having set multiple `urls` the available `relative*Path` etc. from http://docpad.org/docs/meta-data return all the full path but not the rendered URL.

e.g. `/en/some/path/to/my/document/title` where the URL is `/en/title`

How do I get the rendered URL for a document?

Answer (score 0):

Providing you are using eco, you should be able to do:

```
The primary url:
<%- @document.url %>

All the urls:
<%- JSON.stringify @document.urls %>
```

Comment: ... but how to get the **rendered** URL?

Comment: What do you consider the rendered URL? What does it look like?

Comment: e.g. document at path `/en/some/path/to/my/document/title` where the **rendered** URL is `/en/title`

Comment: Hrmmm. Can you provide the code for how you set these "rendered" URLs?

Comment: That's what you're doing, can you provide the code for how you do it?

Comment: ... sure `urls: ["/shortcut-alternative", "/shortcut-name"]`

Comment: So is there any way to get the requested URL within a document when parsing it in docpad?

Comment: Without seeing the complete source code for this, I am unable to go further on this. The abstractions applied to your examples, remove the potential problem you are facing.

Comment: Setting alternatative URLs from the docs meta data as per http://docpad.org/docs/meta-data is all source required to set them.

Comment: And the solution, how to get the requested alternative URL while parsing a doc in docpad is what I am looking for, hence the question and no source because that's what is requested ... not sure what I am missing?